# With Ubuntu 14.04, get 'Kerneloops BUG: bad page state in process compiz pfn:42c97'

Tags: drivers, nvidia, compiz

currently using a 'NVIDIA GF108 GeForce GT 620 rev a1' card

With this new card, terminal sessions work but local terminal locked when I started Chrome.  When that happens, remote connections (VNC) are fine.
With old card, local terminal locked up very soon after booting.

System has:
motherboard: Intel D975XBX2
proc: Intel Core2 quad 2.66G
ram: 2G DDR2 800Mhz

suggestions appreciated
thanks!